# ko.mapping.defaultOptions().include should be an array or string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout js and I am trying to clone a view model in order to add it to a grid. 
This is what I am doing:

```
var newModel = new ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(self));
```

But I get:

```
Error: ko.mapping.defaultOptions().include should be an array or string.

...fault:a[d]=g}}return a}function i(){var a=e.utils.arrayPushAll([{},q],arguments)...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `new` keyword:

```
var newModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(self));
```

But it is a bad way for creating copies. If you are using `jQuery` too try this:

```
var newModel = jQuery.extend(true, {}, self);
```

Comment: var newModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(self)); doesn't work for me, but the jquery version did. Why is backbone is bad for creating copies?

Comment: It is knockout mapping, not backbone. It is bad because it does many redundant mapping operations instead of just cloning the object.

Comment: No, this is not working well because I don't want to copy the bindings! after cloning using jQuery, if I change the inputs elements, the cloned object changed also!

Comment: Why does this: var newModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(self)); throws that exception for me?..